# How to add EmbeddedResource to project with dotnet CLI?

Tags: .net-core, csproj, dotnet-cli

I've got some resources that need to be embedded in the DLL. If I use Visual Studio I can add them using the UI. This will add the following to the `csproj` file:

`<EmbeddedResource Include="Mocks\MyMock.GetDimensions().json" />`

No I like to add the resource with a `dotnet` command from the terminal. How would I go about?

<sub>I'm (re)generating some files in PowerShell and I need to embed these files in the DLL so it can be accessed by my code.</sub>

Comment: Hard to guess how dotnet.exe could be useful.  If you want to jockey this from the command line then you have to use the C# compiler's /resource option.

Comment: I'm (re)generating some files in PowerShell and I need to embed these files in the DLL so it can be accessed by my code.

Comment: Then add `<EmbeddedResource Include="Mocks\**\*.json" />` and it should embed all the files that are in the folder without the need to modify the csproj for each file.

Comment: Didn't know about the ** syntax... might make things way easier.

Comment: Works like a charm!!

Comment: added it to my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in verb in the CLI that handles this. This would have to be done by a 3rd party CLI command line tool installed into the project (also by editing the csproj file) or a 3rd party global tool (support for global tools is coming in the 2.2.0 CLI).

For your specific use case, adding all json files through a wildcard is the easiest option to include all generated content:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Mocks\**\*.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Is this still the case in .NET 5?

Comment: Yes it is, only resx is an embedded resource by default